# Is it possible to stop checking further validations when the first one fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation, fluentvalidation-2.0

Otherwise I always need to check if the value is `null` before performing any other validations. It's kinda annoying if I have many custom checks that are using `Must()`.

I placed `NotEmpty()` at the very top of it therefore it already returns false, is it possible to stop there?

#### Example

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name)
    .NotEmpty() // Can we not even continue if this fails?
    .Length(2, 32)
    .Must(x =>
    {
        var reserved = new[] {"id", "email", "passwordhash", "passwordsalt", "description"};
        return !reserved.Contains(x.ToLowerInvariant()); // Exception, x is null
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&=ANCHOR#Cascade). It's called CascadeMode and can be set on an individual rule like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Name)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Length(2, 32);
```

Or it can be set globally with:

```
ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
```

Note: if you set it globally, it can be overridden with `CascadeMode.Continue` on any individual validator class or on any individual rule.